# PNG files in photography workflow

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, fujifilm, workflow, png

I shoot Fujifilm and like the builtin film sims. Capture One, does a good job at reproducing them, but I find sometimes Fuji JPEGs better, particularly when some proprietary features (e.g Color Chrome FX) or alternative film simulation recipes are used, since they cannot be reproduced as is in a photo editor like C1 (only X Raw Studio can help somewhat).

Some folks do light basic editing (crop, perspective & lens correction, ...) of the jpegs but the operation is lossy, since every time you do something on the jpeg file, you lose some image quality.

I do sometimes convert the JPEGs to PNG and edit the latters in C1, considering that once converted in PNG, you kinda "freeze" (in theory) the image quality of the original JPEG, until you do a final conversion to JPEG.

I didn't find information about such a workflow (JPEG > PNG > Edit > PNG).

So questions are:

- Does it make any sense and offer the possibility of some limited of the JPEG file editing without loss of quality ?
- Does editing of a JPEG file in Capture One preserve its original image quality ?

Comment: @RomeoNinov You *can* have more than 8 bits per channel with PNG!

Comment: I think any workflow editing images that were the result of previous edits is broken. That's why people hype on "non-destructive" editing (like in Adobe's Lightroom). As a side effect you can undo any previous edits *without any loss of quality*.

Comment: First, color Chrome FX is no nostalgia and second, you can consider the use of a film simulation as an in camera preset (instead of editor). Both are an artistic choice and can give a specific mood to the picture. 
Point was to kinda get the best of both worlds with further editing (dodging & burning, etc.)

Comment: @U.Windl yes you can, but 16-bit PNGs compress much worsely than 8-bit ones. You could just as well use uncompressed (for faster loading and saving) TIFF then.

Comment: @Ruslan Probably because of the entropy: For 8-bits resolution you'll have more similar pixels than you'll have with 16-bit resolution. It has nothing to do with compression or bit resolution per se, but if you preserve more details, the result will be larger.

Comment: @U.Windl maybe, but when increasing color depth by 2 times results in an image 10 times larger, it makes compression sort of useless: it only takes time with almost no useful result. This is why I'd use an uncompressed image instead.

Comment: @Ruslan Sorry, I cannot reproduce: I rendered a sphere shaded with three colors at 1024x768 with 16-bit resolution in GIMP, then exported it in different formats. The 16-bit PNG was 123kB, and the 8-bit PNG was 94kB. So the "increase" would be around 1.3 (not 2, and specifically not 10). Make sure you have a reproducible workflow (PNG can also store 32-bit floats, and those are getting *really huge*). However when I converted the image to a 256-color indexed image using dithering, the result when being saved was 237kB for a 8-bit resolution in PNG.

Comment: @U.Windl I don't remember which image resulted in ~10× increase in size, but here's an example of a 16-bit 85MiB PNG and a requantized 8-bit 23MiB one: [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nsK4B59qytwsI9JDtjx__ZDxPGirv8Az?usp=sharing). Not a 10× difference, but still 3.7×, which is quite a bit more than 2×.

Comment: First the theoretical factor is 6 (two bytes instead of one for each R,G,B). If you really get a factor like 10, you might have added more channels or layers I suspect.

Answer (score 9):

I think your understanding is incorrect. Converting a JPEG to PNG doesn't magically aid in quality preservation as you edit an image. Essentially, when an image is opened in an editor, the filetype that the image had been *stored as* is irrelevant; you are simply dealing with pixels that each have a RGB value. (These are 8-bit values in the case of JPEG.) When you push these pixel values around (i.e. applying edits to the image), new RGB values are calculated for the pixels. It doesn't matter if the image was a camera-original JPEG file or a PNG file saved from that original, the RGB values are going to be the same.

The difference comes when the image is *re-saved* as JPEG. It's at that moment that lossy compression is applied for JPEG files, and that's where quality is theoretically lost. If you were to save as PNG or TIFF, no lossy compression is applied. (Personally I prefer TIFF – probably things have changed, but there was a time when PNG didn't support colour profiles.) Re-opening these 2 hypothetical JPEG / PNG files can result in different RGB values for some pixels. This loss in quality however, based on re-saving a high-quality JPEG file as a high-quality JPEG file, *one time*, is negligible. You won't notice it. Still, if you intend to apply further edits, it makes sense to save your file using an image format that doesn't apply lossy compression.

The big difference is between 8-bit and 16-bit files. When you push pixel values around in a 16-bit file (i.e. applying edits to the image), then new RGB values are calculated with more precision, and there's more "room" for gradation between colour values. Especially for editing, 16-bit images are more, let's say, "desirable" than 8-bit images.

This explanation is a simplification, but hopefully adds something.

Comment: Yes it does add! Thank you. 
I understand that an acceptable workflow could be:
 get the JPEG either SOOC or from X Raw Studio, 
import it in C1, 
do the edits, 
than save it as PNG.

... but work the RAW file in case of tricky pictures

Comment: Saving a TIFF in e.g. Photoshop does allow jpeg compression as an option (none, LZW, Zip, and jpeg), obviously using this compression option causes the same quality-loss issue you mention. One problem with 16-bpp is that exporting/converting to 8bpp for general use and distribution introduces dithering and quantization. Usually imperceptible but can be seen in e.g. gradients.

Comment: @osullic Your first paragraph would not be correct if applied to raw files. When one applies adjustments to raw files the pixels showing on the screen are not modified, the actual raw data (which is not even remotely what is visible on the screen) is reconverted using the new instruction set.

Answer (score 5):

If you want manufacturer-quality editing, filters/LUTs etc, use the manufacturer's software.

If you want to edit further after that, use 16-bit TIFF.

Only ever go to 8-bit at final export.

Yes, this makes for some heavy file sizes, but HDs are cheap these days.

<sup>A bit breif for an answer, but didn't want to post as a comment …and didn't really have much else to add;)</sup>

Comment: With current display technology (I'm talking about maximum contrast) exporting to 8 bits eventually is obsolete IMHO. To avoid color banding, you probably want 10 bits at least.

Comment: Never saw any banding in SOOC JPEG files. 
I guess it's the result of further JPEG processing.

Comment: @fmplayer yes you can see banding at 8 bits per channel, U. Windl is right.  Someone once gave me a sample that shows it well, and I made a computer generated copy just to convince myself that it wasn't artifacting.  SOOC can mask the effect if there's any noise in the image at all, noise breaks up the edges that make it easy to see.

Comment: @U.Windl it's possible to go from 16 bits to 8 without visible banding, if you use dithering.  The problem is that nobody does that, and it isn't effective with JPEGs.

Comment: @fmplayer Any SOOC JPEG depends on how the camera's JPEG conversion engine is processing the raw data. So each camera, with each possible combination of in-camera settings that affect raw-to-JPEG conversion, can depict the same scene differently. Some cameras do much better than other cameras with scenes that might be prone to banding, and some combinations of settings will do better than others for the same camera.

Comment: @Mark Ransom To my knowledge, jpeg banding is primarily due to either the use of too strong a compression factor or multiple successive writings of not minimal compression, not to the 8 bit encoding per se.

Comment: @fmplayer but I wasn't speaking of JPEGs.  I have a test image that is losslessly saved as a PNG and you can clearly see banding in it.  Yes, JPEG has its own set of problems that make it worse.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you considered it but each major camera manufacturer has their own raw file developing software which should produce same image as in-camera JPEG (you might check it yourself using raw+JPEG pairs of images produced by camera). For sure Fujifilm has it too and it provides a lot of output options. It's named X-RAW Studio in your case.

Comment: I mentioned XRS in the question. Problem is that it does not allow some editing features like layers, which is useful for dodging and burning

Comment: @fmplayer can it export anything more than JPEG?

Comment: It depends on the camera. Some, like GFXes or XT4 can for sure. Check recent Xpro series and recent expensive cameras like xt5 and xh2

Comment: @fmplayer I was rather asking about XRS. Exporting hit bit depth image from camera would be waste of space if XRS can do it and the image quality might be better from XRS too.

Comment: XRS works with the camera's processor, not the computer's. Hence only parameters accessible to the camera can be tweaked (which is plenty btw). Image quality is that of the camera, no less no more, same for output format.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers; if you want your edits to be "lossless" you should convert the file to a 16bit tiff and edit it in C1 using layers and layer masks; keeping the original file/base layer unedited.

That way all edits can be reverted without loss of the original data. Save the the working file tiff with lossless compression with all layers.

Comment: No need to overkill with TIFF. JPEG and PNG files can also be added layers in C1. C1 considers a JPEG file like a RAW in that matter.

Comment: @fmplayer, but only a tiff can be saved keeping the layers intact.

Comment: Even a 16-bit TIFF does not preserve all of the information in most raw files. White point and black point are baked in with conversion to TIFF. WB is, to a lesser degree, also baked in. 16-bit gives more latitude than 8-bit color does, but the monochromatic luminance values contained in most raw files are not preserved at all in a 48-bit (16-bits per color channel) TIFF.

Comment: @Steve Kersting Once a file, be it RAW or JPEG or whatever has been imported in C1, both the original file and the layers are preserved by C1